# The value of variable is not showing while sending email using phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRYAH.png) i have written a code which sends invoice details via email after completing the order. but the issue is that when  i am running this code in a file.php it is working fine and giving me all the value of variable and executing the while loop
But while mailing, the while() function is not getting execueted and the invoice details are appearing null in the email.
The mail consist of details of the shopping which the user had done.

```
function sentInvoice($conn,$oid)
{
  $url="http://localhost/user/contactus.php";
  $date=date('Y');
  $nego=0;
  $res=mysqli_query($conn,"select order_details.*,product.id,product.pname,orders.total_price from order_details inner join product on product.id=order_details.product_id inner join orders on orders.id=order_details.order_id where order_details.order_id='$oid'");
  $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"select orders.*, ecom_users.id,ecom_users.fname,ecom_users.email  from orders inner join ecom_users on ecom_users.id=orders.uid where orders.id='$oid'"));
  $total=0; 
  $dateArr=explode(" ",$row['added_on']);
  $order_date=$dateArr[0];
   $html='<body>
      <span class="preheader">This is an invoice for your purchase on '.$order_date.'.</span>
      <table class="email-wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <table class="email-content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
              <!-- Email Body -->
              <tr>
                <td class="email-body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <table class="email-body_inner" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                    <!-- Body content -->
                    <tr>
                      <td class="content-cell">
                        <div class="f-fallback">
                          <h1>Hi '.$row['fname'].',</h1>
                          <p>Thanks for using Our Website ShopHana. This is an invoice for your recent purchase.</p>
                          <table class="attributes" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="attributes_content">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="attributes_item">
                                      <span class="f-fallback">
                <strong>Amount:'.$row['total_price'].'</strong>
              </span>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="attributes_item">
              </span>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <!-- Action -->
                          
                          <table class="purchase" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <h3>'.$oid.'</h3>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <h3 class="align-right">'.$order_date.'</h3>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2">
                                <table class="purchase_content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                  <tr>
                                    <th class="purchase_heading" align="left">
                                      <p class="f-fallback">Description</p>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="purchase_heading" align="right">
                                      <p class="f-fallback">Amount</p>
                                    </th>
                                  </tr>';
                                  while($rem=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                                  {
                                    
                                    $pid=$rem['product_id'];
                                    $user_id=$row['uid'];
                                    $a_query=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"select negotiate from addtocart where pid=$pid and uid=$user_id"));
                                    $nego=$a_query['negotiate'];
                                    echo $nego;
                                    if($nego!=0)
                                    {
                                        $total=$total+$nego;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $total=$total+$rem['price'];
                                    }
//this part is not showing up in the email
                                    $html.=' 
                                    <tr>
                                    <td width="80%" class="purchase_item"><span class="f-fallback">'.$rem['pname'].'</span></td>
                                    <td class="align-right" width="20%" class="purchase_item"><span class="f-fallback">'.$rem['price'].'</span></td>
                                    </tr>';
                                 
                                  }
                                  $html.='<tr>
                                    <td width="80%" class="purchase_footer" valign="middle">
                                      <p class="f-fallback purchase_total purchase_total--label">Total</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="20%" class="purchase_footer" valign="middle">
                                      <p class="f-fallback purchase_total">'.$total.'</p>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <p>If you have any questions about this invoice, simply reply to this email or reach out to our <a href="'.$url.'">support team</a> for help.</p>
                          <p>Cheers,
                            <br>The ShopHana Team</p>
                          <!-- Sub copy -->
                          
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class="email-footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="content-cell" align="center">
                        <p class="f-fallback sub align-center">&copy;'.$date.' ShopHana All rights reserved.</p>
                        <p class="f-fallback sub align-center">
                          [SHOPHANA, LLC]
                          <br>1234 Street Rd.
                          <br>Suite 1234
                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>';
include('smtp/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail=new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port=587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure="tls";
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->Username="somemail9245@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password="passwords";
    $mail->SetFrom("shophana2337@gmail.com");
    $mail->addAddress($row['email']);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject="Invoice Details";
    $mail->Body=$html;
    $mail->SMTPOptions=array('ssl'=>array(
        'verify_peer'=>false,
        'verify_peer_name'=>false,
        'allow_self_signed'=>false
    ));
    if($mail->send()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: add your html within the while loop

Comment: also deleted your email password don't post that here

Comment: But, adding it to the html is giving me the whole while code in the mail

Comment: Try echo not html .= within the while loop

Comment: it is not working

Comment: What do you get can i see a screenshot ?

Comment: i have edited the question there is a link for image

Comment: Is the while function working here as expected?

Comment: while mailing it is not working if i'm executing the code by filename.php then it is working fine and giving the output